# Setting the index with 'id' in CakePHP's find('all') method

Tags: php, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have an array with data, all with their own unique ID. I'm using the ORM method find('all') and the resulting array looks somewhat like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Wijken] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Naam
                    [lat] => 13.37
                    [lon] => 13.37
                    [zoom] => 14
                )

        )

)
```

From my Routing I'm receiving an unique ID.. 
What I want, is re-use my array and get the data from, let's say, ID 1.

So what I need is that the indexes of my associative array (returned by find('')) are being set with the id of the "Wijken"-object itself.

I explained everything, just in case people have a different approach. Querying the database again with the param ID is not acceptable though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try [Set::combine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1492/combine)

To maintain find('all') structure (from icc97 comment):

```
$idsAsIndexes = Set::combine($wijkens, '{n}.Wijken.id', '{n}');
```

Alternatively you can also extract a single model:

```
$idsAsIndexes = Set::combine($wijkens, '{n}.Wijken.id', '{n}.Wijken');
```

hope that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: I didn't know about this function. Thanks for notify.

Comment: If you want to maintain the same array structure as with find('all') i.e. including the 'Wijken' key you need `$wijkensWithIdsAsIndexes = Set::combine($wijkens, '{n}.Wijken.id', '{n}');`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to have your id as a key in the array, and don't even think it is possible with Cake without doing something "funny".

But if you do a find all, I'd have to assume you are going to process the data and do a loop at some point, at which time you could have something like:

```
foreach ($wijkens as $wijken) {
    [...]do the general things here[...]
    if ($wijken['Wijken']['id'] == $url_id) {
        [...]do the thing you want to specifically do to id = 1 here[...]
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I understand you don't want any extra query, although it seems like a relative minor transaction cost to me, and is still what I would prefer.

Comment: Yes, this approach is my backup. And I don't wanna do anything funny, indeed. I was just hoping that CakePHP would have a solution.